# ¿Como añadir un Action<> como TValue en un diccionario?

Tags: c#, diccionarios

Tengo estas dos listas:

```
List<IEvent> iEvent = new List<IEvent>();
List<IEventListener> listeners = new List<IEventListener>();
```

Y quería sustituirlas por dos diccionarios.

```
private Dictionary<IEvent, Action<EventInfo, Type, Property> eventSender;
private Dictionary<IEventListener,Action<EventInfo, Type, Property>> eventListerner;
```

Esta era la funcion original para añadir EventSenders:

```
public void AddSender(IEvent sender)
{       
    if (!iEvent.Contains(sender))
    {
        iEvent.Add(sender);
        isEventAdded = true;
    }
}
```

Y queria sustituirlo por esto porque a veces me interesa saber a que objeto pertenece el evento:

```
public void AddSender(IEvent sender)
{
    eventSender.Add(sender, sender.OnEvent); //-->error
}
```

Tengo un mensaje de error que me dice que "sender.OnEvent" solo puede ir a la izquierda de += o -=

Me ocurre exactamente lo mismo con la función de añadir Listeners

```
public void AddListener(IEventListener listener)
{
    listeners.Add(listener);
    
    foreach (IEvent sender in iEvent)
    {
        sender.OnEvent += listener.Listen;                      
    }
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de poder añadir "sender.OnEvent" en el diccionario?

Muchas gracias!!

//---------------------------------------------------

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

//--------------------------------------------------

OnEven viene de esta interfaz:

```
public interface IEvent 
{
    public event Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> OnEvent;
    public void SendEvent(EventInfo sendInfo, EntityEvent.Type eventType, Property property);
}
```

//---------------------------------------------------

El problema tiene algo que ver con la interfaz o la clase que la implemeta porque he declarado lo siguiente dentro de la misma clase donde está la funcion AddListener() y no me da ningún error...

```
public event Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> tmp;
```

//--------------------------------------------------------

La diferencia que veo es que uno es abstracto y la otra no...

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: no es  eventSender.Add(sender,Delegate sender.OnEvent);

Comment: No funciona... continua dandome el mismo error... creo que tiene algo que ver con que sea miembro de otra clase porque he declarado un delegado exactamente igual en la misma clase y no me da ningún error.... pero necesito que este en la otra clase... de hecho es el unico miembro que implenta de la interfaz IEvent.... Vo a añadir la interfaz ahi arriva para que la veas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta pregunta pone a tambalear los fundamentos de muchos, pero la respuesta es sencilla: Tu no puedes hacer un diccionario de eventos, los más parecido es un diccionario de delegados.

Un **event** agrega capas de abstracción y protección sobre un delegado (o apuntador a función) esta protección por definición solo permite agregar y remover elementos a la lista de invocaciones pero no es en sí una referencia al apuntador a función (delegado, función anónima).

Esta solución no response exactamente al problema, pero tiene un enfoque que puede ayudar a resolverlo. Esta sugerencia no pasa la letra O de los principios SOLID (Open extension/Closed to changes) pues modifica la interfaz.

```
public class EntityEvent
{
    public class Type
    { 
    }
    public class Property
    {
    }
}


public delegate void MethodEvent(EventInfo eventInfo, EntityEvent.Type type, EntityEvent.Property property);

public interface IEvent
{
    public event Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> OnEvent;
    public MethodEvent GetEventDelegate { get;}
    public Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> GetEventAction { get; }
    public void SendEvent(EventInfo sendInfo, EntityEvent.Type eventType, EntityEvent.Property property);
}

public interface IEventListener
{
    public event Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> OnEvent;
    public void SendEvent(EventInfo sendInfo, EntityEvent.Type eventType, EntityEvent.Property property);
}

public class ImplementedEvenet : IEvent
{
    private Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> evnt;

    public Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> EventImplementation { get => evnt; }

    MethodEvent IEvent.GetEventDelegate => 
        delegate(EventInfo eventInfo, EntityEvent.Type type, EntityEvent.Property property ) 
        {
            evnt(eventInfo, type, property);
        };

    public Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> GetEventAction => evnt;

    public event Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> OnEvent
    {
        add
        {
            evnt = value;
            OnEvent += value;
            Console.WriteLine("Implement");
        }
        remove
        {
            OnEvent -= value;
            Console.WriteLine("Remove Implementation");
        }
    }

    public void SendEvent(EventInfo sendInfo, EntityEvent.Type eventType, EntityEvent.Property property)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EVENT");
    }

    
}

public class Foo
{
    private Dictionary<IEvent, Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property>> eventSender = new();
    private Dictionary<IEvent, MethodEvent> eventSenderDelegate = new();
    private Dictionary<IEventListener, Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property>> eventListerner = new();

    public Foo()
    { 
        
    }

    public void AddSender(IEvent sender)
    {
        eventSenderDelegate.TryAdd(sender, sender.GetEventDelegate );
        eventSender.TryAdd(sender, sender.GetEventAction );
    }
}
```

Fuentes:

Definición del evento:

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155/what-are-the-differences-between-delegates-and-events

Información aclaratoria.

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848332/how-do-i-make-a-dictionary-of-events

Convertir System.Action a Delegado.

[3] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328589/action-to-delegate-new-action-or-casting-action

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan elaborada respuesta. Estoy impresionado, ya pensaba que hacerlo era imposible!!